# How can i convert these from column to rows with first 3 phone numbers

Tags: sql, ssms

```
This is the original table columns:

    SELECT
        e18.customer_id,
        CASE
            WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'PRIMPHONE' THEN 1
            WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'SECPHONE'  THEN 2
            WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'HOME'      THEN 3
            WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'CELLPHONE' THEN 4
            WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'WORK'      THEN 5
            WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'PHONETLO'  THEN 6
            WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'CIF'       THEN 7
        END as phone_type,
        PHONE_NUMBER
    FROM [spectrum].[dbo].[s_phone_number_e18] e18
    WHERE e18.CUSTOMER_ID IN(38,118888)
    ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID, phone_type


CUSTOMER_ID phone_type PHONE_NUMBER
    1   38            4        6812060
    2   38            5        4873960
    3   118888        3        6565657
    4   118888        4        5675751
    5   118888        5        7176873
```

--So, I'm able to convert the above from rows to columns using Pivot:

```
    SELECT [CUSTOMER_ID],PRIMPHONE,SECPHONE,HOME,CELLPHONE,WORK,PHONETLO,CIF FROM
    (SELECT customer_id,[PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE], PHONE_NUMBER FROM [spectrum].[dbo].[s_phone_number_e18] e18 wHERE e18.CUSTOMER_ID IN(38,118888)
    ) tab1 
    PIVOT  
    (  
    max(PHONE_NUMBER) For [PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE] IN ([PRIMPHONE],[SECPHONE],[HOME],[CELLPHONE],[WORK],[PHONETLO],[CIF])) AS Tab2  
    ORDER BY Tab2.customer_id


[CUSTOMER_ID] PRIMPHONE SECPHONE HOME   CELLPHONE  WORK     PHONETLO    CIF
38               NULL   NULL     NULL     6812060  4873960   NULL      NULL
118888           NULL   NULL     6565657  5675751  7176873   NULL      NULL
```

--The challenge I'm facing is how to get like for each of the customer id, following the order as

```
WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'PRIMPHONE' THEN 1
    WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'SECPHONE'  THEN 2
    WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'HOME'      THEN 3
    WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'CELLPHONE' THEN 4
    WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'WORK'      THEN 5
    WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'PHONETLO'  THEN 6
    WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'CIF'       THEN 7

for 1st 3 phone numbers.
```

Final output looking for:

```
[CUSTOMER_ID]   Phone 1   Phone 2  Phone 3
38               6812060  4873960   NULL
118888           6565657  5675751  7176873
```

--Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If I'm following you right.  You want the column order returned to be the same order as 1-7... ie: PRIMPHONE1 , SECPHONE, HOME, CELLPHONE, WORK, PHONETLO, CIF.  If that's the case, just reorder your column return.  If that is not the case and you want it to be agnostic of the phone type and simply return the first 3 possible phones then a bit of code change is needed and I can help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out.  I think this is what you are asking for right?

```
CREATE TABLE #T(
    Customer_ID INT
    ,PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE VARCHAR(30)
    ,PHONE_NUMBER INT
)

INSERT INTO #T (
    Customer_ID
    ,PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE
    ,PHONE_NUMBER
)
VALUES
    (38, 'CELLPHONE', 6812060)
    ,(38, 'WORK', 4873960)
    ,(118888, 'HOME', 6565657)
    ,(118888, 'CELLPHONE', 5675751)
    ,(118888, 'WORK', 7176873)


;WITH CTE_T AS (
    SELECT
        e18.customer_id,
        CASE
            WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'PRIMPHONE' THEN 1
            WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'SECPHONE'  THEN 2
            WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'HOME'      THEN 3
            WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'CELLPHONE' THEN 4
            WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'WORK'      THEN 5
            WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'PHONETLO'  THEN 6
            WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'CIF'       THEN 7
        END as phone_type,
        PHONE_NUMBER
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e18.Customer_ID ORDER BY CASE
                                                                        WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'PRIMPHONE' THEN 1
                                                                        WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'SECPHONE'  THEN 2
                                                                        WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'HOME'      THEN 3
                                                                        WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'CELLPHONE' THEN 4
                                                                        WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'WORK'      THEN 5
                                                                        WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'PHONETLO'  THEN 6
                                                                        WHEN PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = 'CIF'       THEN 7
                                                                    END) AS RN
    FROM #T e18
    WHERE e18.CUSTOMER_ID IN(38,118888)
    AND e18.PHONE_NUMBER IS NOT NULL --only return records that have a phone number
)
--LEFT OUTER JOIN Method (since you only need 3 returns.  You could also pivot it if you want instead of left outer joining.
SELECT 
    T.Customer_ID
    ,T.PHONE_NUMBER AS [Phone 1]
    ,T1.PHONE_NUMBER AS [Phone 2]
    ,T2.PHONE_NUMBER AS [Phone 3]
FROM
    CTE_T T
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    CTE_T T1
    ON T1.Customer_ID = T.Customer_ID
    AND T.RN = T1.RN - 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    CTE_T T2
    ON T2.Customer_ID = T.Customer_ID
    AND T.RN = T2.RN - 2
WHERE
    T.RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. It's absolutely perfect. Could you please explain me what is this RN -1 ,

Comment: i.e. AND T.RN = T1.RN - 1

Comment: If you run the CTE section of the code by itself, you will see the base set of data.  You will see that there is a RN associated to each record (a row number).  The RN-1 allows you to manipulate the column value.  IE, when RN = 2, subtract 1 from it and force it to be a 1.  This way you will find a match back to the original row.

Comment: as I need to join some other table to get the output. So, can I get the answer without the use of the CTE expression?

Comment: You could create it as a subquery or you could put the results of the CTE into a temp table.

Comment: can you please help me with that, when you are convenient.

Answer (score 0):

[ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is good to use in cases like this. I would do something like this:

```
SELECT 
CUSTOMER_ID,
PHONE_NUMBER,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID
      ORDER BY PHONE_NUMBER
   ) row_num
INTO #TEMP
FROM 
   s_phone_number_e18
ORDER BY 
   CUSTOMER_ID;


SELECT t1.CUSTOMER_ID, t1.PHONE_NUMBER, t2.PHONE_NUMBER, t3.PHONE_NUMBER
FROM #TEMP t1
LEFT JOIN #TEMP t2 ON t1.CUSTOMER_ID = t2.CUSTOMER_ID
LEFT JOIN #TEMP t3 ON t1.CUSTOMER_ID = t2.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE t1.row_num = 1 and t2.row_num = 2 and t3.row_num = 3
```

Comment: It's giving me the output as the same Cusomter_Id for same phone numbers
like this:
CUSTOMER_ID PHONE_NUMBER  PHONE_NUMBER PHONE_NUMBER
52823                     2049197                2049197           7686222
52823                     2049197                2049197           9141049

Comment: Make sure you have the last line in the query, I forgot it and edited the post: "WHERE t1.row_num = 1 and t2.row_num = 2 and t3.row_num = 3"

Comment: Sefan, getting the same issue.